# How to make form field conditionally required

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a drop down list that is visible under a certain condition.
How can I make it required if it is visible?

```
 <div class="col-md-6" ng-show="vm.UserList.length > 0">

    <label for="Users">{{vm.Resources.Model}}</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="users" ng-change="vm.OnSomething()" ng-model="vm.UserId">
        ....
    </select>

</div>
```

On my other required dropdowns I have the "required" attribute on them:

```
 <select class="form-control"  required="" ... >
```

If the ng-show is true, how can I set the required attribute on my dropdown?

Comment: Just: `ng-required="vm.UserList.length > 0"`.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez is right, and you can even make it shorter!: `ng-required="vm.UserList.length"`

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `ng-show="vm.UserList.length > 0` with `ng-if="vm.UserList.length > 0`

In this case the dom element will not be present only if the condition is true & `required` attribute will be added.

If the `ng-if` condition fails then the dom element won't be present at all in dom

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**ngRequired**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired) directive.

> [**ngRequired**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired) adds the required validator to ngModel. It is most
>   often used for input and select controls, but can also be applied to
>   custom controls.

By using: `ng-required="vm.UserList.length > 0"`.

In the image below you can see how its adds the `required` attribute in the `select` control.

[image]

See in action:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("app", []);
  app.controller("Controller", [function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.UserList = [{
      "UserId": 1,
      "UserName": "User 1"
    }, {
      "UserId": 2,
      "UserName": "User 2"
    }, {
      "UserId": 3,
      "UserName": "User 3"
    }];
    vm.Resources = {};
    vm.Resources.Model = "Field";
    vm.remove = function(i) {
      vm.UserList.splice(i, 1);
    };
  }]);
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller as vm">
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-show="vm.UserList.length > 0">
      <label for="Users">{{vm.Resources.Model}}</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="users" ng-change="vm.OnSomething()" ng-model="vm.UserId" ng-required="vm.UserList.length > 0">
        ....
    </select>
      <br />
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in vm.UserList">
          <span ng-bind="user.UserName"></span> <button type="button" ng-click="vm.remove($index)">X</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```